# How do I return a value in column C only if Column A and B matches my criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

SO this started as me trying to help someone else, got stumped.  So basically i have values in columns B, C, and D.  if have my criteria in H2 and I2 and when my criteria in H2 and I2 matches in B and C then have the corresponding answer in D to populate J2.  basically a vlookup with 2 criteria.
  i have something like this.

```
Sub test()
Dim rngCrit1 As Range
Dim rngCrit2 As Range
Dim rngAnswer As Range
Dim strTarget As String

Set rngCrit1 = Range("H2")
Set rngCrit2 = Range("I2")
Set rngAnswer = Range("J2")


Range("B2").Select
strTarget = ActiveCell.Value

Do While strTarget <> ""
    With ActiveCell
        If strTarget = rngCrit1 Then
            If .Offset(0, 1).Value = rngCrit2 Then
            rngAnswer.Value = .Offset(0, 2)
        Else
    .Offset(1, 0).Select
    strTarget = ActiveCell.Value
    End If
    End If
    End With
Loop



End Sub
```

Now this thing just crashes, no debugging or anything. I am self taught so i'm sure i screwed the pooch here somewhere.

*Note this is just to satisfy my own interest not really important, so if it takes you more than 5 min please help someone else that needs it more than I.

```
Val1    Val2    Val3                Crit1   Crit2   Answer
a           r   12              g       v        22
b           r   14                      
c           s   15                      
d           s    16                     
e           t    18                     
f           t   19                      
g           y   20                      
g           v   22
```

sample data

Comment: Could you add a row or two of sample data as well? Just to help with working through the problem.

Comment: Hi Phil, i just added it to the bottom.  Sorry not familiar with how to create a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's great that you're trying to improve your VBA skills. The first thing I'd suggest, which will improve any macro you write, is to avoid using `.Select`. Work directly with the range objects. For instance:

```
Range("B2").Select
strTarget = ActiveCell.Value
```

becomes

```
strTarget = Range("B2").Value
```

Also, in general, use `vbNullString` or `Len(variable)=0` when checking for "empty" values instead of `""`. As for why your program is crashing, it may be your use of `With`. Like `Select`, it should be avoided in most cases (definitely in this one). Although you update `ActiveCell`, it's within the scope of the `With` statement, so once you close it (`End With`), those changes to `ActiveCell` are undone (I would suggest stepping through the macro and watch the values of `strTarget` and `ActiveCell`). This may not be the case, but I know it holds for other variables, which is why I avoid `With` (and avoid reassigning values in a `With` statement)

Anyway, I'd add the following code and rewrite the loop as follows:

```
Dim r as range
set r = Range("B2") 'keep in mind this range is on the ActiveSheet, so you're better
                'off explicitly naming the Sheet e.g. Sheet1.Range("B2")

strTarget1 = Range("B2").Value
strTarget2 = Range("C2").Value

Do While Len(strTarget) <> 0
    If strTarget1 = rngCrit1 Then
      If strTarget2 = rngCrit2 Then
        rngAnswer.Value = r.Offset(0,2)
        Exit Do
      End If
    End If

    set r = r.Offset(1,0)
    strTarget1 = r.Value
    strTarget2 = r.Offset(0,1).Value
Loop
```

Keep in mind you could also loop with a `Long` counter `i` for the row, then call `Sheet1.Cells(i,1).Value`, `Sheet1.Cells(i,2).Value` and so on for the values of the different columns of that row (instead of using a range object and `.Offset`

**EDIT:** After running your code, the reason for the crash is due to your `If` statements. You want to go to the next cell regardless. Remove the `Else` and put the `End If` statements before the `Select`. Add an `Exit Do` after your assignment statement in the 2nd `If`, since you want to stop looping if your two columns meet the criteria. I've updated my code to show this, as well.

Comment: +1 for a nice explanation. I'm not sure I agree `With` should be avoided in general, but agree it is not necessary here.

Comment: I use `With` blocks when doing lots of changes directly to the object in question (usually for lots of formatting or where lots of properties must be dealt with). They can be useful, but I've had issues with variable scope before so I'm careful when I do so. I'm also updating my answer about the cause of his crash.

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX` and `MATCH`, or `SUMPRODUCT` tend to work well for this. An example of the former:

```
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/59482
```

Comment: Hi, i know sumproduct will work, but i'm just trying to sharpen my VBA skills.  I'm just frustrated because i thought i had this.

Answer (score 1):

if you can guarantee val1 and val2 will be unique (e.g. when searching for g & v, there is only 1 line with g and v) then you can use sumifs
I put val1,val2 and val3 in columns A,B, & C, and the search into E,F and the answer in G, and came up with this formula
`=SUMIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,E2,B2:B9,F2)`
of course, this fails if val3 is not numeric, or there are more than 1 line with the letters you are looking for

Comment: Yeah i can do it with a formula i guess i'm just trying to brush up on my VBA skills, i just really wanna know why my macro isn't working.  you know that level in that video game that you think youre doing everything right but still keep dying?  yeah its like that.